# Sql Update a table values from another table using distinct and where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Here is the screnario, i have2 tables table1 and table2 and i need to update the table1 using table2 as there are quite a few duplicate in table2 but need to pick one using the where clause in table2

```
Table1(unique table)
    Email_Address|Country|Region|Source|PP|PS
    a@a.com IN AP SS ES PP
    b@g.com US AM ES ST PO

Table2(duplicate values)
    Email_Address|Country|Region|Source|PP|PS
    a@a.com IN AP SS ES PP
    a@a.com ES AP SS ES SST
    a@a.com IN AP MS ES P
    a@a.com IN AP NS ST PP
    b@g.com US AM ES ST PO
    b@g.com IN AP NS ST PP
```

Now i need to get the distinct values from Table2 where the source is SS and need to be mapped against the Table1 email.

I'm using something like this but is not working,

```
Update Table1
Set Table1.Country=Table2.Country,Table1.PP=Table2.PP
Where Email_Address In (Select Distinct Email_Address 
From Table2 
where Table2.Source = 'SS')
```

any help would be a helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update   t1
set      Source = 'SS'
,        PP = t2.MaxPP
from     Table1 t1
join     (
         select  Email_address
         ,       max(PP) as MaxPP -- Pick max PP from the available group
         from    Table2
         where   Source = 'SS'
         group by
                 Email_address
         ) t2
on       t2.Email_address = t1.Email_address
```

If there is more than one matching `PP` value in `Table2`, you have to a choice. The above example picks the maximum.  If that's not what you're looking for, please clarify your question.

Comment: thanks Andomar for the prompt reply actually i need to update the values that's present in the table2 because i have even other source where dynamic.. i think i have given a wrong example of query let me change that please.. so that you would know what i'm trying to achive..

Answer (score 0):

For this type of update, you can use the `from` clause.  What you want to do is select a single row for each email address where the source is "SS".  The following chooses a randome row using `row_number()` and `newid()`:

```
Update t1
    Set Source = t2.Source,
        PP = t2.PP
    from table1 t1 join
         (select t2.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by email_address order by newid()) as seqnum
          from table2 t2
          where t2.Source = 'SS'
         ) t2
         on t1.email_address = t2.email_address and seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Hi gordon, does this take the rest of the values from the same record or gonna take it from another match like if a row pop's up with country in and when try to update the pp column does it take the same row value.. just a doubt.. thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Gordon Linoff, i'm getting an error near seqnum.. kindly please help

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?  `row_number()` has been supported since 2005.